# Why did this code break on me?

Tags: plotting, functions, function-construction

Code was executing normally till I got an error message

> "Tag Times in (x\ Sin[4\ x])[x_] is Protected."
> [image]

```
g[x_] := x^5 - 2 x + 3
h[x_] := -9 x - 40
k[x_] := Sin[x^2] + 13
po = List {};
p1 = AppendTo[po, 
   x /. FindRoot[Sin[x^2] + 13 == -9 x - 40, {x, -6}]];
p2 = AppendTo[po, 
  x /. FindRoot[Sin[x^2] + 13 == x^5 - 2 x^2 + 3, {x, 2}]]; p3 = 
 AppendTo[po, x /. FindRoot[x^5 - 2 x^2 + 3 == x Cos[5 x], {x, -1}]];
p4 = AppendTo[po, 
   x /. FindRoot[x Cos[5 x] == -9 x - 40, {x, -4.25}]];
po1 = List {};
AppendTo[po1, k[x] /. x -> po[[1]]];
AppendTo[po1, k[x] /. x -> po[[2]]];
AppendTo[po1, f[x] /. x -> po[[3]]];
AppendTo[po1, f[x] /. x -> po[[4]]];
ep1 = Join[{po[[1]]}, {po1[[1]]}];
ep2 = Join[{po[[2]]}, {po1[[2]]}];
ep3 = Join[{po[[3]]}, {po1[[3]]}];
ep4 = Join[{po[[4]]}, {po1[[4]]}];
p = ListPlot[{ep1, ep2, ep3, ep4}, PlotStyle -> Black];
plo1 = Plot[{f[x], g[x], h[x]}, {x, -8, 5}, PlotRange -> {-17, 17}];
Show[plo1, p, PlotRange -> {-17, 17}]
```

Comment: Use: `Clear["Global\`*"]` at the beginning. Also change `po = {};` and `po1 = {};`. It works on v12.2.0-Win7-x64.

Comment: If you want to know: Something like `a=13+Sin[x]^2; a[x_]:=17` gives this error.

Comment: What is `f[x]`? Maybe `f[x_]=x Cos[5 x]` and   `g[x_]=x^5 - 2 x^2 + 3` instead of `g[x_]=x^5 - 2 x+ 3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Method-1

The code similar with the author. We set `f[x_]=x Cos[5 x]` and rewrite `g[x]` to `g[x_]=x^5 - 2 x^2 + 3` and replace `po = List{}` and `po1 = List{}` to  `po = List[]` and `po1 = List[]`

```
Clear["Global`*"];
g[x_] = x^5 - 2 x^2 + 3;
h[x_] = -9 x - 40;
k[x_] = Sin[x^2] + 13;
f[x_] = x Cos[5 x];
po = List[];
p1 = AppendTo[po, x /. FindRoot[k[x] == h[x], {x, -6}]];
p2 = AppendTo[po, x /. FindRoot[k[x] == g[x], {x, 2}]];
p3 = AppendTo[po, x /. FindRoot[f[x] == g[x], {x, -1}]];
p4 = AppendTo[po, x /. FindRoot[f[x] == h[x], {x, -4.25}]];
po1 = List[];
AppendTo[po1, k[x] /. x -> po[[1]]];
AppendTo[po1, k[x] /. x -> po[[2]]];
AppendTo[po1, f[x] /. x -> po[[3]]];
AppendTo[po1, f[x] /. x -> po[[4]]];
ep1 = Join[{po[[1]]}, {po1[[1]]}];
ep2 = Join[{po[[2]]}, {po1[[2]]}];
ep3 = Join[{po[[3]]}, {po1[[3]]}];
ep4 = Join[{po[[4]]}, {po1[[4]]}];
p = ListPlot[{ep1, ep2, ep3, ep4}, PlotStyle -> Black];
plo1 = Plot[{f[x], g[x], h[x], k[x]}, {x, -8, 5}, 
   PlotRange -> {-17, 17}];
Show[plo1, p, PlotRange -> {-17, 17}]
```

[image]

### Method-2

To solve `k[x] == g[x]` and `k[x] ==h[x]` we use the `MeshFunctions`,that is
`{k[#] - g[#] &, k[#] - h[#] &}` and set `Mesh->{{0}}` etc.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
g[x_] = x^5 - 2 x^2 + 3;
h[x_] = -9 x - 40;
k[x_] = Sin[x^2] + 13;
f[x_] = x Cos[5 x];
plotk = Plot[k[x], {x, -8, 5}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {k[#] - g[#] &, k[#] - h[#] &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[5], Black], 
   PlotStyle -> Red];
plotf = Plot[f[x], {x, -8, 5}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {f[#] - g[#] &, f[#] - h[#] &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[5], Black], 
   PlotStyle -> Blue];
plotg = Plot[g[x], {x, -8, 5}, PlotStyle -> Orange];
ploth = Plot[h[x], {x, -8, 5}, PlotStyle -> Green];
Show[plotg, ploth, plotk, plotf, PlotRange -> {-17, 17}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much